# Difference between Application Documents Directory and Support Directory in path_provider?

Tags: flutter, path, audio-player, file-manager

I am new to path_provider. I am making a music app and want to download an mp3 file but I don't know which is the right way to download the file within the application.

I want to store the file with application storage so users can not access it directly.

so where i can store it?

```
final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final dir2 = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
print(dir.path);
print(dir2.path);

<---------- Output of path ----------->
/data/user/0/com.oraysa/app_flutter.  
/data/user/0/com.oraysa/files
```

together with this one more question is how can I access downloaded files ( get info of all downloaded files). how can I find the same file so next time I don't have to download it again, instead just directly load it from storage?

Answer (score 0):

**1.- Which directory should you use?**

According to path_provider docs both directories are blocked for user access, but applicationDocumentsDirectory is meant for:

> data that is user-generated, or that cannot otherwise be recreated by your application

So, since songs can be recreated by your aplication, you should use applicationSupportDirectory

**2.- How can you list downloaded files?**

For this you could use the default dar library `dart:io`

```
final dir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();    
final Files = io.Directory(dir.path).listSync();
```